# Unable to upload sketch using Platformio (but Arduino IDE works)

Tags: arduino-ide, sketch, uploading, avrdude, clones

I am using an Arduino Nano (Clone) which I was programming with the Arduino IDE (Version 1.8.5 on Mac OS X 10.10.5).

Using the Arduino IDE I need to re-plug the Nano before uploading, but after doing this everything works as expected and the sketch is being uploaded successfully.

I then tried to use Platformio core (CLI) and get the well-known `not in sync` error:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xe0
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

As said, this error is well-known, esp. in relation to Arduino clones, and reported several times around the Internet with different solutions.

I just wonder how Arduino IDE is able to upload the code successfully, but Platformio is not since both Arduino IDE and Platformio CLI are just calling `avrdude` to upload the code.

Remark: Uploading the same code to an Arduino Uno works like a charm with both using Arduino IDE and Platformio.

---

*Updates due to further investigation:*

I enabled verbose output for both Arduino IDE and Platformio showing the exact `avrdude` command executed to upload the built hex-file. I adopted the call to `avrdude` from Arduino IDE with the path of the compiled Platformio code. This works as expected:

```
avrdude -v -p atmega328p -c arduino -b 57600 -D -P /dev/cu.usbserial-00000000 -U flash:w:.pioenvs/nano/firmware.hex:i
```

I then had a look at the command used by Platformio which is quite similar but provides an additional `-C` for a config-file:

```
avrdude -v -p atmega328p -C /Users/Albert/.platformio/packages/tool-avrdude/avrdude.conf -c arduino -b 57600 -D -P "/dev/cu.usbserial-00000000" -U flash:w:.pioenvs/nano/firmware.hex:i
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to run this command from the Terminal due to an error:

```
avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Dec 16 2013 at 17:26:24
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/Users/Albert/.platformio/packages/tool-avrdude/avrdude.conf"
avrdude: syntax error at /Users/Albert/.platformio/packages/tool-avrdude/avrdude.conf:1080
```

Comment: try to upload to Nano with Uno selected as board

Comment: @Juraj: Using `Uno` instead of `Nano` does not work as well.

Comment: has Platformio an "old bootloader" option for Nano?

Comment: There is a 'normal' and a 'new' option. Both not working. The only difference seems to be the baud rate at first glance. I might have a look at the upload scripts for further differences...

Comment: I've tried replicating this issue using a nano clone on mac os 10.12.6 using platformio IDE, and there were no issues. I would try two things: upload a simple blink sketch (or an empty loop) using arduino IDE to make sure the board doesn't try to connect over UART thus interfering with the upload process under platformio; and if this doesn't help, then I would re-flash the bootloader. Also, if platformio is not up to date, it is certainly a good idea to update it to make sure it uses the latest avrdude + config file.

Comment: @Im_Int: Updated to Arduino 1.8.7 and tryied to reflash boot-loader. Reflashing did not work with Arduino 1.8.7 but with 1.8.5. After that still not able to upload code using Platformio. Tried another Arduino Nano clone: Was able to upload code once with Platformio, but never again. Uploading with Arduino IDE 1.8.7 works, unable to re-flash bootloader to this board as well. There are several discussions around the Internet about the transfer protocol, the use of reset signal on Reset pin (RST) and a capacitor. So this might me a hardware/board-related issue due to cheap Arduino clones... :/

Comment: how do you flash the bootloader?

Comment: I used/tried to use an Arduino Uno as ISP since I do not have my original AVR ISP mkII on hand currently

Comment: and why did you do that? is it possible that you changed to different bootloader?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I'm abandoning platform io because of this. It's rather more difficult than the arduino IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Please use board = nanoatmega328new in your platformio.ini